# header function trouble in hosting

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm programming a simple login system. It runs very good in local, but when i run in my hosting i'm getting troubles with the header function.

Heres my login form:

```
<form method="post" action="auth.php">
                User:<br />
                <input type="text" name="name" required><br /><br />
                Password:<br />
                <input type="password" name="pass" class="input" required><br /><br />
                <button>LOGIN</button>

</form>
```

And the "auth.php":

```
include '../conection.php';

$user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$pass = sha1($mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));

if(isset($user)){

$users = $mysqli->query("select * from admins where admin_user='".$user."' and admin_pass='".$pass."' ");

if($users->fetch_object()){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        //Im having troubles with this function
        header('Location:control.php');
        exit;

}else{
    echo 'Sorry no access<br /><br />';
    //if i remove the "//" to the next header function works in local and hosting
    //header('Location:index.php');
} 

}else{
echo 'Sorry no access<br /><br />';
 }

$mysqli->close();
```

WARNINGS:
1st: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter.
2nd: Cannot modify header information.

Whats wrong in the code? Or what i'm not considering?
Also if you have any advice to improve this code, I really appreciate.

For your help, thanks.

Comment: you should consider using prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php, and use 
[password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) of PHP

Comment: try changing the name of your file. instead of auth.php make it a authenticate.php. I got this weird problem also before

Comment: @RobertDeanPantino  i dont think file name makes any difference

Comment: did you try?

delete your auth.php and change your action into authenticate.php

or if you want you can use `<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="control.php"</script>`

instead of header

Comment: @RobertDeanPantino The "auth.php" it's just an example. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? How does it not work?

Comment: @JohnConde it doesn't redirect to control.php

Comment: Try putting a space after the colon

Comment: *"i'm getting troubles with the header function."* - Define "troubles". Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. If you get a `headers already sent` warning, let me know. You're probably going to get an error about the `$us` variable.

Comment: This variable `$us` in `if($us = $users->fetch_object())` is sitting in limbo, you're not doing anything with it. Which is why your header's not working. Try `if($users->fetch_object())`

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're totally right, i Have 2 warnings: **1st: "session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter". 2nd: Cannot modify header information**. And the variable $us you're right too. Now I only fetch the $users variable.

Comment: Give me a minute, I'm just finishing up writing an answer.

Comment: @Christian Consult my answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm reading. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code that follows, I've put the code to run all on its own, by changing the action to `action=""` and adding an [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to a new submit button. You can split them up afterwards.

Don't use `<button>LOGIN</button>` with the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` conditional statement, it won't work. It is based on the new submit button I've included below.

To first outline the errors:

`if($us = $users->fetch_object())` - `$us` is a stray variable that is not doing anything; it needs to be removed.

The line needs to read as `if($users->fetch_object())`

The following also needs to be removed; there isn't a corresponding `if` condition for it:

```
else{
echo 'Sorry no access<br /><br />';
 }
```

You're already stating it in: (but don't use echo with header)

```
else{
    echo 'Sorry no access<br /><br />';
    //if i remove the "//" to the next header function works in local and hosting
    header('Location:index.php');
}
```

In regards to `headers already sent` that is caused by the echos and header, plus check to see if you may have a space before your opening `<?php` tag, or a [**byte order mark**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (save your files as UTF-8 without BOM). That could be a contributing factor, should you still get that error after removing the echos.

Make sure there is nothing above it. You can probably get away using [`ob_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) following your opening `<?php` tag.

The `echo $user` is causing this, so just remove it and use the header. Keep `echo` to TEST with only, but comment out the header when doing so. You should not be echoing anything above header, HTML, etc.

This `echo 'Sorry no access<br /><br />';` is where you should remove it. It's either `echo` or `header`, you can't use both.

You can read up on the `headers already sent` here:

- **[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/)**

**Code:** (see comments in code)

```
<?php

include '../conection.php';

$user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$pass = sha1($mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $users = $mysqli->query("select * from admins where admin_user='".$user."' and admin_pass='".$pass."' ");

    if($users->fetch_object()){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            //Im having troubles with this function
            header('Location:control.php');
              exit;

    // echo $user; // don't use this with header

    }else{
        // echo 'Sorry no access<br /><br />'; // don't use this with header
        //if i remove the "//" to the next header function works in local and hosting
        header('Location:index.php');
        exit;
    } 


} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

$mysqli->close();

?>

<form method="post" action="">
                User:<br />
                <input type="text" name="name" required><br /><br />
                Password:<br />
                <input type="password" name="pass" class="input" required><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<br>

</form>
```

Comment: Puuum! Fred I really appreciate all your help, your answer was very helpful and works. I hope someday return this favor. Just another little bit question: what do you recommend me to continue learning? Regards.

Comment: @Christian  You're very much welcome Christian. You can read up on [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*. They're a bit more work, but well worth the effort, *believe me*. Plus, if you've something particular in mind, Stack is a good place to go through the many questions and *accepted* answers. You can Google too, which many a time, will most likely lead you back here on Stack :)

Comment: @Christian Another thing I recommend you use is [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). `sha1` isn't the best hashing method; many don't like using it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice and for taking the time to respond. We read soon.

Answer (score 0):

The header() function sends a raw HTTP header to a client.

It is important to notice that header() must be called before any actual output is sent

Answer (score -1):

To start with use prepared statements [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Second do this:

```
header('Location: control.php');
exit;
```